# Windows 8 won't resolve local network shares while offline

Tags: networking, windows-8, smb

Recently replaced an old computer running XP with one running Windows 8.1.

This computer is connected to an unmanaged switch (local only, no internet), as is an old (~'95)Hyundai machining centre running Windows for Workgroups (this cannot be upgraded). The machining centre presents a network share named \V800.

The old XP box had no trouble connecting to this. The new one, however, will only connect when the switch is plugged into a router connected to the internet. This is an issue as I don't want to keep the ancient machines connected to the internet.

I can only presume this is due to a change in Windows. Network discovery and file sharing is turned on for Public networks.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the switch at all?  Or could a crossover cable be used?

Comment: It sounds like a name resolution problem to me. What internal name resolution mechanism are you using? DNS? Broadcasts? What happens if you add an entry in the Windows 8.1 Hosts file (DNS) or LMHOSTS file (NETBIOS) for the machining center PC (as a test)?

Comment: I need the switch. There is another computer and another mill connected to it. As for name resolution I couldn't tell you. I'm not a Windows guy. It's a virgin Win8.1 install.Given that the only way I can address the Hyundai is via \\V800 (which I cannot reach), and I have no router on which to find the IP. How would I find the IP of the machine to put in my hostfile? You can't actually use Windows on the machine. Only a Siemens machining interface which loads at boot.

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt on the Windows 8.1 computer run the following: `ping V800`. If ping fails to resolve the name V800 to an ip address then it's a name resolution problem.

If step 1 fails (meaning there's no name resolution) then run a MAC address scanner from the Windows 8.1 computer. Then look for a MAC address identified as belonging to Hyundai and make note of the ip address associated with that MAC address (some MAC address scanners will identify and display the `owning` organization of the MAC address). If the MAC addresses aren't identified then you can punch them in here to look them up and identify them:

https://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html

You can also browse the following list. The first 6 characters (the first three sets of characters) of the MAC address identify the `owning` organization.

http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt

Once you've identified the ip address for the Hyundai device you can add an entry for it in the LMHOSTS file on the Windows 8.1 computer. You'll need to run notepad with elevation in order to edit and save the LMHOSTS file. The reason you want to use the LMHOSTS file is because you need to resolve a single-label name (NetBIOS), which is what the LMHOSTS file is for (as opposed to the HOSTS file which is used to resolve FQDN's). Then from a command prompt on the Windows 8.1 computer run `nbtstat -R` to reload the NetBIOS name cache.

Comment: Angry ip scanner may be of use here http://angryip.org